# How to Stop auto sending Delivery Status Notifications in Thunderbird

Tags: email, thunderbird, spam-prevention

I'm using thunderbird and I have the odd spammer which is sending emails with a delivery status notification which is basically telling them that we are a living person and to send more.

Is there a way to stop or at least prompt me before these notifications are sent.

FYI, i'm NOT talking about return receipts.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be only a part of MTA settings how to treat the NDR or DSN, not Thunderbird. The bounce message, when explicitly requested, is composed by the MTA, like exim4.